# Compiling eos software to get dlls

Tags: eosio-code, compilation, library, eosio-cpp

How can I compile EOS software on Linux or Windows to get dynamically linked libraries (DLLs) that I need in order to create an EOS wrapper to compile and deploy smart contracts from other programming languages, such as Java, C# etc?